# Create a stored procedure for APPROVED OR REJECT USERS

Tags: plsql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcE5Z.png)

I have this user table.
and i created a CRUD for it to get add and update users.

now i wanted to create a stored procedure to approve or reject users.
which will give
0= checker , 1= maker
0= pending , 1= approved, 2= reject

Comment: I have no idea what is that procedure supposed to do. Probably update table whose description you posted. But, update *which* column(s)? Which parameters would that procedure accept? How come you didn't manage to do it yourself (if you already created CRUD)?

Comment: if checker =0 in users table and status = pending then it should show me or print that users type is checker and its status is pending. This procedure will accept user id as input parameter and against that id it will return that if the user type is checker or make and status is pending or rejected.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure check_user (p_user_id IN varchar2,
                                        p_user_type OUT varchar2,
                                        p_user_status OUT varchar2) is

  cursor c_user is select user_type, user_status
                   from your_user_table
                   where user_id = p_user_id;

begin
  open c_user;
  fetch c_user into p_user_type, p_user_status;
  if c_user%notfound then
    p_user_type := 'unknown';
    p_user_status := 'unknown';
  end if;
  close c_user;
end;
```

/